# Is this a travel under Euroleague basketball rules?

Tags: rules, basketball

In basketball's Euroleague, a player who is stationary receives the ball. A few seconds after receiving the ball he steps back and after both of his feet touch the ground he shoots. Is this a travel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Euroleague plays under [FIBA Rules](https://www.fiba.basketball/documents/official-basketball-rules.pdf); in that rulebook, travelling is defined thusly:

> Establishing a pivot foot by a player who catches a live ball on the playing court:
>
> > • A player who catches the ball while standing with both feet on the floor:
> >
> > > ▬ The moment one foot is lifted, the other foot becomes the pivot foot.
> > >
> > > ▬ To start a dribble, the pivot foot may not be lifted before the ball is released
> > >       from the hand(s).
> > >
> > > ▬ To pass or shoot for a field goal, the player may jump off a pivot foot, but
> > >       neither foot may be returned to the floor before the ball is released from the
> > >       hand(s).

Thus, if a player is stationary and receives the ball, they may pick up *one* foot and replace it, or may pick up *both* feet and replace *neither* foot (passing or shooting in the air), but may not pick up *both* feet and replace *both*.